# SwiftUI button, adding a frame to its contained view overrides the button's contentShape

Tags: button, swiftui, shapes

I need to make a button whose hit area has the shape of its content instead of a default `Rectangle()`, and it happens that such content is a user-defined shape. The problem is, when I add a `.frame` modifier to the button's contained view, SwiftUI seems to automatically ignore its `.contentShape` modifier.

This is the code that's giving me this problem:

```
@State private var gkAreaSize: CGSize = .zero
   
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            ZStack(alignment: .topLeading) {
                Button(action: {
                    // whatever, irrelevant logic for this thread
                }) {
                    GKDeptStoreShape()
                        .frame(
                            width: GKDeptStoreShape.normalizedAABB.width * self.gkAreaSize.width,
                            height: GKDeptStoreShape.normalizedAABB.height * self.gkAreaSize.height
                        )
                        .overlay {
                            Text("Dept. Store")
                                .minimumScaleFactor(0.1)
                                .allowsTightening(true)
                                .lineLimit(1)
                                .font(.headline.weight(.semibold))
                                .foregroundColor(.white)
                                .padding()
                        }
                }
                .contentShape(GKDeptStoreShape())
                .offset(
                    x: GKDeptStoreShape.normalizedAABB.origin.x * self.gkAreaSize.width,
                    y: GKDeptStoreShape.normalizedAABB.origin.y * self.gkAreaSize.height
                )
            }
            .frame(idealWidth: 1168.0, idealHeight: 714.0)
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
            .frame(maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .top)
            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
            .saveSize(in: self.$gkAreaSize)
        }
    }
```

Where `.saveSize` is a custom view modifier defined like this:

```
struct SizeCalculator: ViewModifier {
    @Binding var size: CGSize
    
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .background(
                GeometryReader { proxy in
                    Color.clear
                        .onAppear {
                            size = proxy.size
                        }
                        .onChange(of: proxy.size) { newSize in
                            size = newSize
                        }
                }
            )
    }
}
```

This is my custom shape's definition:

```
struct GKDeptStoreShape: Shape {
    static private let origin = CGPoint(x: 433, y: 336)
    static private let size = CGSize(width: 313, height: 152)
    
    static let normalizedAABB: CGRect = CGRect(
        x: GKDeptStoreShape.origin.x/1168.0,
        y: GKDeptStoreShape.origin.y/714.0,
        width: GKDeptStoreShape.size.width/1168.0,
        height: GKDeptStoreShape.size.height/714.0
    )
    
    /// The list of points, starting from the closer to the top left origin, clockwise
    static private let points: [CGPoint] = [
        CGPoint(x: 2.0/313.0, y: 1.0/152.0),
        CGPoint(x: 75.0/313.0, y: 1.0/76.0),
        CGPoint(x: 132.0/313.0, y: 11.0/38.0),
        CGPoint(x: 180.0/313.0, y: 11.0/38.0),
        CGPoint(x: 237.0/313.0, y: 3.0/38.0),
        CGPoint(x: 311.0/313.0, y: 3.0/38.0),
        CGPoint(x: 311.0/313.0, y: 8.0/19.0),
        CGPoint(x: 215.0/313.0, y: 69.0/76.0),
        CGPoint(x: 201.0/313.0, y: 143.0/152.0),
        CGPoint(x: 170.0/313.0, y: 151.0/152.0),
        CGPoint(x: 140.0/313.0, y: 151.0/152.0),
        CGPoint(x: 117.0/313.0, y: 145.0/152.0),
        CGPoint(x: 95.0/313.0, y: 135.0/152.0),
        CGPoint(x: 1.0/313.0, y: 31.0/76.0),

    ]
    
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        var path = Path()

        for i in 0..<GKDeptStoreShape.points.count {
            let nextPoint = GKDeptStoreShape.points[i]
                    .scale(x: rect.maxX - rect.minX, y: rect.maxY - rect.minY)
                    .translate(x: rect.minX, y: rect.minY)
                    
            if i == 0 {
                path.move(to: nextPoint)
            } else {
                path.addLine(to: nextPoint)
            }
        }
        
        return path
    }
}
```

Here `.scale` and `.translate` are two custom modifiers defined like this:

```
import CoreGraphics

extension CGPoint {
    func scale(x: CGFloat, y: CGFloat) -> CGPoint {
        return CGPoint(x: self.x*x, y: self.y*y)
    }

    func translate(x: CGFloat, y: CGFloat) -> CGPoint {
        return CGPoint(x: self.x + x, y: self.y + y)
    }
}
```

With this code, the whole bounding box (rectangle) around the shape is tappable, even though its background is implicitly `.clear` (making it explicitly `.clear` didn't solve). Weirdly enough, removing the `.frame` modifier from `GKDeptStoreShape()` inside the `Button` solves the issue, as only the filled area becomes tappable. What's the issue here? How do I make only the `GKDeptStoreShape()` filled area tappable, without removing the frame modifier?

Comment: Does it have to be a `Button`? Why not just put a tap gesture on the view that has the content shape.

Comment: @Yrb: Possibly a button, at least for accessibility and visual tap feedback purposes. I also found that setting a `background` modifier to the button makes the hit test work properly, but I'd rather have a `.clear` background for the button.

Comment: You can do all of that with a view. Sometimes, you can't make standard SwiftUI APIs like buttons do what you want, so, make your own button that takes an irregular shape, handles the feedback and handles accessibility.